# How to make bullets points like this in latex?

Tags: symbols

I tried different methods but i am not getting this output
[image]

```
\section{Relevant Course Work}
 \resumeSubHeadingListStart
 \newlist{inlinelist}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist*[inlinelist,1]{label=\textbullet,
                        itemjoin={{ \ }}}
                        

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\begin{inlinelist}

    \item Data Cleasing  \& Transfpormation
    \item Statistical \& Data Analisys
    \item Feature Design \& Implementation
    \item some other text
    \item two words
    \item Technique Validation
    \item Business Development
\end{inlinelist}
```

Image attached is my desired output

my Output - [image: My Output]

Comment: How does the list grow up: horizontally meaning next element is to the right and then down to the next row or vertically?

Comment: it goes horizontally - my list looks something like this •DBMS •OS •SE •CN •SP •AI     I am not able to space my bullet points

Comment: I've attached my lists image

Comment: You could treat it as a 4 col table, and put a bullet symbol first (I think it‘s in pisymbol.sty or so). Once it works abstract each cell into a macro, so you could enter sth. like \elem{DBMS} into your table cells. There are many ways to typeset it.

Comment: If you cross-post on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of your question in every version of your question!

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/75231244/2777074

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a package called [tasks](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks), which I think does exactly what you need. It's quite flexible with many options to influence lists. Here's an example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newlength\bullen

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\parindent=0pt
\footnotesize
{\scshape
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{}}
        Relevant work \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}}
\begin{tasks}[
        label={$\bullet$},
        label-width = 12pt,
        label-offset=0pt,
        item-indent=12pt,
        label-align = left,
        column-sep = 12pt,
    ](4)
    \task Data Cleasing  \& Transfpormation
    \task Statistical \& Data Analisys
    \task Feature Design \& Implementation
    \task some other text
    \task two words
    \task Technique Validation
    \task Business Development
\end{tasks}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it worked